# Wordpress 6.1.1 UTF8 Slug Limit Increase

Tags: permalinks

I have recently updated my Wordpress to 6.1.1 and my site uses UFT8 Characters (Thai) in permalink by increasing wp_posts -> post_name from 255 varchar to 3000 and also enabling

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL']) ) {
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];}
```

in **wp-config.php**

after the update the Wordpress I have lost the limit of varchar in post_name to 255 and pages started showing 400 bad request.

now after changing the post_name to 3000 again its still not working but only works if it resave the product page. Is there a way to solve this ?

reference website - https://delivery.doubleapaper.com/

specific product which shows 404 - (copy paste URL) delivery.doubleapaper.com/product/double-a-care-alcohol-%e0%b9%81%e0%b8%ad%e0%b8%a5%e0%b8%81%e0%b8%ad%e0%b8%ae%e0%b8%ad%e0%b8%a5%e0%b9%8c-%e0%b8%82%e0%b8%99%e0%b8%b2%e0%b8%94-20-ml-%e0%b8%a5%e0%b8%b2%e0%b8%a2%e0%b8%99%e0%b9%89

Answer (score 0):

You Can Go To Your **Cpanel** Or **Hosting Panel** Then Go To **Select PHP Version** Then Click On **Options** And There You Will Be Able To See **Max File Upload Size** You Can Increase Or Decrease File Size From There As Preferred.

Comment: Do you mean upload_max_filesize or post_max_size ?